# MK_CONTROL flag cleared during drag-copy operation

Tags: mfc, drag-and-drop, ole, stingray

I'm using Stingray Objective Views on top of MFC for a canvas editing application.  I've recently started having a strange problem, where the control key setting is cleared for drag-copy operations (that is, if I have an object on the canvas and I hold the CTRL key down while moving it should make a copy instead of moving the original object).

What is strange I've found that if I put a breakpoint at the start of COleDropTarget::XDropTarget::DragOver then I can see that the MK_CONTROL flag is always set for the dwKeyState parameter, and the drag-copy works properly.  But if there is no breakpoint then the MK_CONTROL flag is usually not set, even though I'm holding the CTRL key down.

Does anyone know what might be causing the problem?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Stingray software but. . .

The question:
Was it working before?
How do you know the flag is not set? 
If it is set with the breakpoint, it should be set without breakpoint in the same memory location.

If you are sure it is cleared, it must be cleared after the breakpoint.
If it was working before and stopped (providing you are running the same version of the code) , most likely the culprit is not your app.

If it stopped working after charges, most likely changes in the code are causing this problem; it could be your code or some kind of a bug in stingray part.
You have mentioned using COleDropTarget. If you have source for stingray, see if it contains any drag/drop customization.

Comment: > The question: Was it working before? ... Yes, when I originally wrote the code I spent a couple of weeks working on it and never had this problem.

Comment: > How do you know the flag is not set? ... When I remove the breakpoint (call it breakpoint A) I can set another breakpoint (call it breakpoint B) at a different place in the code that will only be hit if the flag is not set.

Comment: > If it is set with the breakpoint, it should be set without breakpoint in the same memory location.  ... That is what I would expect, but it is not what is happening.  Maybe some kind of multi-threading problem?

Comment: > If you are sure it is cleared, it must be cleared after the breakpoint. ... When I hit my breakpoint B (see above) I can trace the call stack back to the point where breakpoint A used to be, and I can see that it has already been cleared by that point.

Comment: > If it was working before and stopped ... I made changes to my code, and Stingray also has drag/drop customization, so it could be either of those things that are causing the problem.  However, I've walked through all of this code several times and can't find the problem.  I guess I'm looking for any tips that might help me approach the problem from a different angle, given the symptoms I've described.